# Is possible to calculate the shortest distance between two geometry objects via python?

Tags: python, objects

I need to add new geometry to my scene and it should fit inside a large box without any intersections.

Is it possible to calculate the shortest distance between two geometry objects in space, and check if the objects are intersecting each other via python?

[image]

Comment: Sounds possible, but please define your requirements a bit more. What exactly you want to achieve? Do you want to calculate the distance between the bounding boxes or the distance of the center points? Can you share your code with us? An Image would also be helpful to understand your issue. Be aware: asking multiple questions is not allowed - for the ASCII part, the code of this addon: https://github.com/p2or/blender-vfxtoolbox could help you.

Comment: [This](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13518/2217) answer may help you.

Comment: Short answer is: 2 objects have intersection or not, Long answer is: Distance 'X' between minimal of face/edge/point of 2 objects. http://bankfotek.pl/image/1832980

Comment: @bardzo Please edit your question with this additional information to reopen it. :)

Comment: [mathutils.geometry](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/mathutils.geometry.html) should help. `distance_point_to_plane` or `intersect_point_line` would be the starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the question in your title this is my answer.

To get the distance between two objects use this formula.

$$d = \sqrt{\left(x_2-x_1\right)^2+\left(y_2-y_1\right)^2+\left(z_2-z_1\right)^2}$$

Then the python code is as follow. Comments are included in the code to help you understand what is going on.

```
import bpy
from math import sqrt

lst = []  # create list to store the location info

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:  # iterate over the selection NOTE: two object should be selected
    lst.append(obj.location)  # populate the lst with the location info

# calulate the distance of the two objects
distance = sqrt((lst[0][0] - lst[1][0])**2 + (lst[0][1] - lst[1][1])**2 + (lst[0][2] - lst[1][2])**2)

# display the distance
print(distance)
```

Comment: With vector math, included in blender,  there is no reason to ever use the Euclidean formula as above.   `(obj1.matrix.world.translation - obj2.matrix_world.translation).length` is the global distance between the origins of  two objects `obj1 and obj2`

Answer (score 3):

The lines of the cube sides, the actual closest point might be between any two arbitrary places along those 2 edges, not necessarily just the corners. The origins of the objects are also not relevant (unless they're spheres, which they're not).

Given the above I think this is a better place to start:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213165/find-shortest-distance-between-lines-in-3d

Comment: Add some other reference, maybe a quotation, in case the link you posted expired, got broken or the question is closed or whatever.